Having Trouble Making A Calculator in Kotlin
I was learning Kotlin. After I learned printing, variables, data types and list then I think I should create a Calculator app so this is the code:
fun main() {
    println("Simple Calculator")
    
    println("Enter the first value")
    val num1: Int = readLine().toInt()

    println("Enter the second value")
    val num2: Int = readLine().toInt()

    println("$num1 + $num2 = ${num1 + num2}")
}

But I get this error:
Kotlin: Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type 'kotlin/String?'.

I want that it will convert num1 and num2 to Int so what to do?

This question is similar to: Why "!!" is required when converting the readline string value into int. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The question marked as duplicate gives only half the answer. That's an old question, and now we have readln() which returns a non-nullable String, so there is no longer any need to use !!. or ?.. Just do readln().toInt().

@k314159 that info should probably be posted as a new answer to the dupe target then, no?
